# rails find_or_create_by creates duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For some reason the below code creates duplicates. It doesn't happen always. If I refresh enough times it stops happening. The strange thing is that the "duplicate" it's creating doesn't even match my user id! This is in dev. The User table doesn't even have a user with an id = 1.

```
@food.page_views.find_or_create_by_user_id(current_user)
```

here's my current_user method.

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    session[:user_id] = nil
  end
  helper_method :current_user
end
```

from console:

```
PageView Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "page_views".* FROM "page_views" WHERE "page_views"."food_id" = 2 AND "page_views"."user_id" = 3 LIMIT 1
(4.0ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "page_views" ("created_at", "food_id", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Tue, 25 Sep 2012 01:36:43 UTC +00:00], ["food_id", 2], ["updated_at", Tue, 25 Sep 2012 01:36:43 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 1]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `current_user.id` instead of `current_user`:

```
@food.page_views.find_or_create_by_user_id(current_user.id)
```

The "magic method" wants a `user_id` integer; you're giving it an object instead.